# How to configure Fio to a more accurate result of IOPs

Tags: benchmark, iops

I am using fio to test how much iops my server can offer. My conf file says to write a 20GB file and read it. THe results show iops=27291. But the test last only 10 seconds. I wonder if the test last 2 hours for example, I would have a more accurate result about my server IOPs.

```
# cat fio/fio-readwrite-20g.fio 
[global]
ioengine=posixaio
rw=readwrite
size=20g
directory=/home/ustore/fio
thread=10
write_bw_log=fio-test
write_iops_log=fio-test
write_lat_log=fio-test

[fio-readwrite-20g]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the man page yields

```
   runtime=int
          Terminate processing after the specified number of seconds.

   time_based
          If  given, run for the specified runtime duration even if the files 
          are completely read or written. The same workload will
          be repeated as many times as runtime allows.
```